# New Theme creation

Tags: categories, theme-development

I am looking into creating my first ever WordPress theme. I want to move my current look and feel that I have created via html / css into WordPress.

What I would like, is to have a list of categories on my home page.

Then clicking on one of these categories will bring up a page which will display a list of posts on it with some description of the posts.

Then if you click on a single post in this page it will load up a single page with a single post displayed on to it. (the full description will be displayed here)

I'm not good at PHP as I mainly know HTML and CSS so if someone can guide me through how to do this or even point me in the direction of a related theme I would appreciate it.

an idea of what I want, looks like [this](http://www.xclo.mobi/indextest.html). This one is my current site created in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I found [Ian Stewart](http://themeshaper.com/author/superuser/)'s Theme Development tutorial a wonderful one to start from the scratch with a very little knowledge on WordPress.

> **[How To Create a WordPress Theme: The Ultimate WordPress Theme
>   Tutorial](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/)**

Hope the explanation there could help you a lot to understand which code block's for what. So you can modify yours as you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need **index.php**, **category.php**, **single.php**, **header.php** and **footer.php**.

The code should be something like this:

**index.php**

```
<?PHP
$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
sort($category_ids);
foreach($category_ids as $cat_id):?>
      <!-- Category Start -->
      <div class="category" id="cat-<?PHP echo $cat_id; ?>">
        <!-- Category Title -->
        <div class="cat-title"> <a href="<?PHP echo get_category_link( $cat_id ); ?>">
          <h1><?PHP echo get_cat_name($cat_id); ?></h1>
          </a> </div>
        <!-- // Category Title End -->
      </div>
      <!-- // Category End -->
<?PHP endforeach; ?>

<?PHP get_footer(); ?>
```

**category.php**

```
<?PHP get_header(); ?>
  <?PHP if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <!-- Content Post Start -->
  <div class="content-post">
    <h1><a href="<?PHP the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?PHP the_title(); ?>
      </a> </h1>
  </div>
  <!-- // Content Post End -->
  <?PHP         endwhile;
            endif;
    ?>
</div>
<!-- // Content End -->
<?PHP get_footer(); ?>
```

**single.php**

```
<?PHP get_header(); ?>
<!-- Content Start -->
  <?PHP if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <!-- Content Post Start -->
  <div class="content-post">
    <h1><a href="<?PHP the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?PHP the_title(); ?>
      </a> </h1>
      <div class="post-info">
      <div class="date"><?PHP the_time('M d, Y'); ?></div> BY <?PHP the_author(); ?>
      </div>
    <?PHP echo get_post_image(); ?>
    <?PHP the_content(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- // Content Post End -->
</div>
<!-- // Content End -->
<?PHP get_footer(); ?>
```

At **header.php** you should include you css/js files.

[This link can help you to build the structure of the wordpress theme](http://codebing.com/how-to-create-a-responsive-website/)

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the Parent / Child theme structure in wordpress to develop your own theme and style it as per your need.
Minimal CSS Theme e.g. http://rtcamp.com/rtpanel/